# Apply transition classes to common parent

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

This seems like it would be a common problem, but I am unable to find a solution.

I have a Vue transition like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>Some content</div>
    <transition name="slide">
        <div v-show="somecondition">Some transitioning content</div>
    </transition>
</div>
```

Normally, Vue will apply the transition classes to the inner transitioning div. However, I need the classes to be applied to the `.parent` div so that I can use the classes on sibling elements.

How can I apply the transition classes on the parent instead of the element being disappeared?

Comment: Obviously You can put the transition outside, but I dont think that's what you want. Can you explain why you want this and create a fiddle a well with your use case.

Comment: I have a sibling div that slides along with the transitioning div. It would be useful to move them both with the same transition in CSS. I've figured out a workaround that uses another Vue variable to determine the class on the non-transitioning div, so that the animations align. But it would be much cleaner to change the class on the parent and cascade from there.

What do you mean by "putting the transition outside"? Wouldn't that just cause the entire parent element to disappear?

Comment: Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/Blue_Dragon360/pen/JWLvNg. Obviously, the blue box can be moved by binding a class to the box variable and messing with the CSS, but it would be much more complex than just inheriting from the class.